# Obtener números primos en un rango determinado

Tags: python, python-3.x

Se me solicitó hacer una función, la cual devuelva los números primos desde un rango 2 hasta un parámetro X.

Lo que intenté hacer fue, utilizando el operador módulo, evaluar cada número dentro de dicho rango, y:

- En el caso de que el resto sea cero: Continuar con el siguiente número, ya que no es un número primo.
- Si el resto no es cero: Diminuir el contador (i) en 1
- Si el contador llega a 1, entonces se trata de un número primo. En este caso, se agrega dicho número a la variable 'lista_numeros_primos'

En el momento de ejecutar, desde el Visual Studio Code, simplemente no obtengo respuesta alguna en la consola, no se imprime nada.

```
def primos(prm_max_number):
    """
    This function verifies which numbers are prime
    SCOPE: Range indicated between 2 and argument 'prm_max_number'
    """
    lista_numeros_primos = []
    numbers_2_to_max_number = range(2,prm_max_number)
    for number in numbers_2_to_max_number:
        if number == 2:
            lista_numeros_primos.append(number)
        else:
            i = number - 1
            while i >= 1:
                remainder = number % i
                #Si no es un número primo, que continue con el siguiente número
                if remainder == 0 and i > 1:
                    continue
                i -= 1
                #Si el contador llega a 1, entonces es un número primo.
                if i == 1:
                    lista_numeros_primos.append(number)
                    continue
    return lista_numeros_primos

print(primos(101))
```

Comment: revisa la lógica, porque entras en un bucle infinito. Saca papel y boli, pon columnas por valores y analiza qué pasa en cada caso.

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta las sugerencias y comentarios, quedó así:

```
import math
def primos(prm_max_number):
    """
    This function verifies which numbers are prime
    SCOPE: Range indicated between 2 and argument 'prm_max_number'
    """
    prime_numbers_list = []
    numbers_2_to_max_number = range(2,prm_max_number)
    
    for number in numbers_2_to_max_number:
        #Variable declarations inside for loop
        maximum_posible_divisor = math.ceil(math.sqrt(number))
        isnt_prime = 0
        i = 2

        #'isnt_prime' will take value '1' if the number being
        #evaluated is not prime, and the loop will end.
        while (isnt_prime < 1) and (i <= maximum_posible_divisor):
            if number % i == 0:
                isnt_prime += 1

            i+= 1
        
        if (isnt_prime < 1):
            prime_numbers_list.append(number)
            
    return prime_numbers_list

print(primos(101))
```